# Binding IsEnabled Property in a GridControl.View

Tags: c#, wpf, isenabled, caliburn, devexpress-wpf

I try to bind the `IsEnabled` property in a context menuitem. The context menu is placed in a Devexpress `GridControl.View`.

I assume that the problem is in the DataContext. The barbutton item is searching for the property `HasPermissionDelete` in the DataContext of the grid. But this isn't the datacontext of the viewmodel. My property `HasPermissionDelete` is on the ViewModel.

I'm using caliburn.micro.

Can you help me for fixing this binding?

My xaml code:

```
<dxg:GridControl.View>
    <dxg:TableView x:Name="gridTable" AllowSorting="True" NavigationStyle="Row" MultiSelectMode="Row" AutoWidth="True" AllowEditing="False" AllowFilterEditor="True" AllowDrop="True" AllowGrouping="True" ShowGroupPanel="False" AllowMoveColumnToDropArea="True" SelectedRowsSource="{Binding SelectedUsers}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="RowDoubleClick">
                <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="Edit" />
            </i:EventTrigger>

            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="InitializePrintableSource" >
                    <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=gridTable}"></cal:Parameter>
                </cal:ActionMessage>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

        <dxg:TableView.RowCellMenuCustomizations>
            <dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="btnDelete" Content="{lex:LocText Translations:Delete, Assembly=Prosa.Common.Modules.UserManagement}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=HasPermissionDelete}"/>
        </dxg:TableView.RowCellMenuCustomizations>
    </dxg:TableView>
</dxg:GridControl.View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you use Caliburn Micro you can still fall back to standard XAML binding. I will make the assumption that your DevExpress DataGrid is inside a simple Grid, which is the root element for your Page or UserControl. So, you will have something like this structure:

```
<Grid x:Name="root">

      <dxg:GridControl>
       ...
       (your GridControl.View and everything else here)
       ...
      </dxg:GridControl>
</Grid>
```

So, to avoid using the GridControl's DataContext in your button, you can bind to the DataContext of your root grid, which in this case would be the corresponding ViewModel. Bind your button like this:

```
<dxb:BarButtonItem x:Name="btnDelete" Content="{lex:LocText Translations:Delete, Assembly=Prosa.Common.Modules.UserManagement}" 
IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=DataContext.HasPermissionDelete}"/>
```

You can always get to the datacontext you want in this way, by setting the Name of the element ("root" in this example) and then referring to it in the binding. You can also bind to elements with no name, but the binding expression is much more complicated (you have to use RelativeSource and select the element type).

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your assumption is right. It's in a grid. Unfortunately, If I update my binding and grid-naming like yours, I will get the following error in the output: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=Root'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.HasPermissionDelete; DataItem=null; target element is 'BarButtonItem' (HashCode=56096403); target property is 'IsEnabled' (type 'Boolean')
Can you help me?

Comment: I see that you get in the error the "Root" element with capital R. The binding expression looks ok... when binding fails always make sure of these things: 1. Spelling (everything is case sensitive and intellisense does not help for property or element names), 2. the bound property is public with public get/set accesors, 3. If it's a collection, make sure it's initialized and that it contains something. Let me know, regards.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, it wasn't the Capital R. I assume there is probably a mvvm devex / caliburn-problem. Now I'm working with commands (better for enable/disable). My new binding is: Command="{Binding Path=(dxg:GridPopupMenu.GridMenuInfo).View.DataContext.EditExecutor.EditCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>

Comment: You're most welcome. I'm glad to hear that it's working for you now. Anyway, if you want to try again with the original binding maybe IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=DataContext.HasPermissionDelete, Mode=TwoWay}" works.